70's/80's movie about two aliens that were supposed to be twin brother and sister. Human parents got them from the hospital as babies
Please help me identify this movie.  I saw it twice in the 80's, but it could have been a 70's movie.
There were two aliens that were supposed to be twin brother and sister.  Human parents got them from the hospital as babies.  I remember they wore pink and blue onesies and had extended foreheads.  Not sure why, but I think the boy was Dudley Moore and the girl had reddish-brown hair.  That's all I remember about the movie.

Dudley Moore was 35 years old in 1970. And he played a baby?

This is Slapstick of Another Kind (1982).

A rich, beautiful couple give birth to deformed alien twins who, when their heads are together, are the smartest kids on the planet.

It's a farcical comedy which I found to be painfully unfunny.
The plot involves aliens in space selecting a rich and famous American couple, Caleb and Letetia Swain, and surreptitiously implanting a twin boy and girl within Letetia's womb, hoping the twins will grow up to serve as advisors to humanity.
There's an early scene at a hospital, shortly after the twins, Wilbur and Eliza, have been born; they aren't shown on-screen but are implied to be malformed, freaking the parents out. We don't get to see them until after a fifteen-year timeskip, at which point they're played by Jerry Lewis and Madeline Kahn, who also play the parents.
Wilbur and Eliza wear a blue and pink romper suit, respectively, and the actors playing them have reddish-brown wigs on and prosthetics on their foreheads, ears, and the tips of their noses to enlarge them. As Wilbur, Jerry Lewis vaguely resembles Dudley Moore.


Slapstick of Another Kind (1982)




